# iOS adding a UISearchController is unhiding the NavigationBar

Tags: ios, uitableview, uisearchcontroller

I am having this weird side effect when I use a UISearchController to update my table view (If I select something from the tableview without searching the bug doesn't manifest itself). But when I search, select a cell, and then `popViewControllerAnimated:` for some reason the NavigationBar is no longer hidden. I want to think that this is a bug within iOS and not specific to my code. But I thought I would see if anyone can spot a bug in my code or has any ideas of something I might be doing wrong. I've added `[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];` to my `viewWillAppear` of the `rootView` but the bar doesn't go away until the animation is over.

My TableView/UISearchController code:

```
@interface LBSelectUniversityView()<UISearchResultsUpdating, UISearchBarDelegate>
@property (strong, nonatomic) UISearchController *searchController;
@end

@implementation LBSelectUniversityView {
    NSArray *schoolNames;
    NSArray *searchResults;
}


- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    schoolNames = [[LBUtilities sharedInstance] schoolNames];
    searchResults = schoolNames;
    self.searchController = [[UISearchController alloc] initWithSearchResultsController:nil];
    self.searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self;
    self.searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = NO;
    self.searchController.searchBar.delegate = self;
    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.searchController.searchBar;
    self.definesPresentationContext = YES;
    [self.searchController.searchBar sizeToFit];
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return searchResults.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                      reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    ...
    return cell;
}

- (void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText{
    if ([searchText isEqualToString:@""]) return;

    NSPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSPredicate
                                    predicateWithFormat:@"SELF contains[cd] %@",
                                    searchText];
    searchResults = [schoolNames filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate];
}

- (void)updateSearchResultsForSearchController:(UISearchController *)searchController{
    NSString *searchString = searchController.searchBar.text;
    [self filterContentForSearchText:searchString];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    ...
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does the problem go away if you set `searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = NO`?

Maybe the following is happening:

1. When you start searching, `searchController.active` is set to `YES`. Thus `searchController` calls `[... setNavigationBarHidden:YES]` because `UISearchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = YES` by default.
2. `popViewControllerAnimated:` is called.
3. `searchController.active` is set to `NO`, so `searchController` calls `[... setNavigationBarHidden:NO]`. This causes the navigation bar to be shown.

Comment: Thank you. That solved the problem. So I am assuming your logic is right.

Answer (score -1):

I think once your search results comes back you are reloading your main table and not search table. This is how you should load data on search results table.

```
self.searchController.searchResultsTableView reloadData];
```

Comment: searchResultsTableView is not an attribute of UISearchController

Comment: Please take a look at this [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISearchDisplayController_Class/)